# Button not working correctly in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, button

So I created a "dropdown button" using just CSS and HTML and it works beautifully in Chrome and FireFox. However, in IE the "New Invoice" button does nothing on hover and is positioned weird. Any idea why this is happening?

Here is a screenshot of it in Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPgZa.jpg
And in IE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPgZa.jpg#1

Here is my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .dropdownbutton ul ul { display: none; width:135px; }
    .dropdownbutton ul li:hover ul { display: block; }
    .dropdownbutton ul { list-style: none; position: relative; display: inline-table; }
    .dropdownbutton ul li:hover a { color: #000000; font-weight:800; }
    .dropdownbutton ul li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; }
    .dropdownbutton ul ul { background: #9799cc; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 100%; }
    .dropdownbutton ul ul li { float: none; border-top: 1px solid #4b545f; position: relative; }
    .dropdownbutton ul ul li a { padding: 5px 5px; }
    .dropdownbutton ul ul li a:hover { background: #6d70aa; }
</style>
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="dropdownbutton">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="innerButton" value="New Invoice &#x25BC;" />
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="DoNewInvoiceClick('1');">New General...</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="DoNewInvoiceClick('2');">New Percent...</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="DoNewInvoiceClick('4');">New Retention Claim...</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Also, I have tried using the Bootstrap hover dropdown plugin and I have the same problem.

Comment: Have you used a CSS Reset..?

Comment: Y U NO jsFiddle? [I created one for you](http://jsfiddle.net/VKZ5T/).

Comment: Which IE version(s) have you tested? Have you checked whether your page is in Quirks mode or compatibility mode?

Comment: also, the button itself seems to work fine, the problem is with his alingment. so put the markup that surrounds the button.

Comment: a CSS reset did not fix it. I'm using IE10

Comment: Okay, IE10... but again, have you checked the browser mode? Is it in quirks or compat mode?

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:top` to the list items.

Comment: this didn't seem to fix it

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you gave us a link to the actual page.

Comment: sorry, it's a local website so it's only running on my computer

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're on Compatibility mode. IE10 should display that correctly. Try putting this on the `<head>` section of your website to disable the Compatibility Mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```